# Select the rows with same values

Tags: sql, select

I'm a beginner and learning SQL and currently working on demo emp (employees) table. 
How to select the departments which has equal number of employees?

Comment: number equal to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a count of employees by department with:

```
SELECT dept, count(*) as empcount FROM employees GROUP BY dept;
```

To get a list of all departments and any department that has the same number of employees you can join those results together:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT dept, count(*) as empcount FROM employees GROUP BY dept) a
    INNER JOIN (SELECT dept, count(*) as empcount FROM employees GROUP BY dept) b ON
         a.empcount = b.empcount AND
         a.dept <> b.dept;
```

This is a little odd though. If you have three departments with 10 employees you will get results like

```
+---+----+---+----+
| a | 10 | b | 10 |
| a | 10 | c | 10 |
| b | 10 | a | 10 |
| b | 10 | c | 10 |
| c | 10 | a | 10 |
| c | 10 | b | 10 |
+---+----+---+----+
```